# Uploading pictures to the Media Library: “Specified file failed upload test.”

Tags: media-library

I changed my domain this week and lost most (but strangely, not all) uploaded pictures in the Media Library. When I try to re-upload them I get, "Specified file failed upload test."

I’ve enabled the following settings in wp-config.php but am not seeing any debug output in debug.log:

```
define(‘WP_DEBUG’, true); 
define( ‘WP_DEBUG_LOG’, true ); 
define( ‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’, true );
```

There's also no debug output in either the Apache or PHP error logs. I tail the logs and during the upload, no output.

I've run Health Check and disabled all plugins but it’s still doing it. I've installed mod_security but tried the same with it disabled. (SecRuleEngine Off) I’ve installed Wordfence as well but it should have been disabled during the Health Check disable plugins test.

I tried this in the .htaccess, no good:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Also, the classic browser uploader option silently fails.

Tried the WP Health plugin and it says everything is good.

The wp-content/uploads directory’s permissions are 750. Tried 755.

This may or may not be important: My WP install is linked to my WP account. I wonder if the domain name change boogered something up? All other functionality that I have tested is now successful since the domain name change.

I am on WP 5.1.1. What else can I look at?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed :-) I had set file_uploads = Off in php.ini.